# Run concurrent child processes

Tags: c, multiprocessing, fork

I'm trying to make 3 kinds of processes(1 proc1, 4 proc2 and 5 proc3) and make them run at the same time. I wrote some code, but there seems to be no overlapping, even with `sleep()` function, i.e. processes always run in same sequence. I'm wondering if this is a correct way to create multiple processes.

```
int main() {
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    setbuf(stderr, NULL);
    
    int pid;

    pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork error.");
        exit(2);
    } else if(pid == 0){ //Child
        proc1();
        exit(0);
    } else { //Parent
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            int child2ID = fork();
            if(child2ID == 0) {
                proc2();
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            int child3ID = fork();
            if(child3ID == 0) {
                proc3();
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    while(wait(NULL)) {
        if(errno == ECHILD)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide complete code and also the log of the test output.

Comment: How do you know they always run in the same sequence?

Comment: Maybe if you want the process to execute together (at the same time) you would take a look at thread instead of fork

Comment: @kaylum 
@Emanuel P

I was testing a program simply with `fprintf()` function and `sleep() / usleep()`, while putting loops in functions proc1..proc3.
I am just asking if program I posted is a correct way of using `fork()` to make multiple processes run together or if there is a way to run all processes at the same exact time.

Comment: You haven't answered our questions and requests The fact that you are posting here means that there is something you don't understand. That includes the very conclusion that the processes are run in a given sequence. We need to see the full and exact code as well as the test result to validate your assertions. That is you have not clearly shown the full code, the exact test result and the exact expected result.